# how to send email with asp.net with c #(FeedBack Form)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create a feedback form.
Before that i was trying to make an email application but I could'nt get how to do that.

I found some code on the net.
I understood the code but was not able to resolve the problem.

my default.aspx page contain the following code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Send Email by .Net 2.0</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h2 style="background-color:Brown; color:Wheat; font-family:Verdana; font-size:14px" align=center>Please enter the following requested 
                information below to send us your comments.</h2>
            <table align=center>
                <tr>
                    <td style="height: 26px"><span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;color:Brown;">Your Name:</span></td>
                    <td style="height: 26px"><asp:textbox id="txtName" Width="241" Runat="server"></asp:textbox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;color:Brown;">Your Email Address:</span></td>
                    <td><asp:textbox id="txtEmail" Width="241" Runat="server"></asp:textbox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colSpan="2" ><span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:Brown;">Your Comment:</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colSpan="2" width=100%><asp:textbox id="txtMessage" Width="100%" Runat="server" Height="99" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="400"></asp:textbox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colSpan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=center><asp:button id="btnSendmail" Runat="server" Text="Send Mail" OnClick="btnSendmail_Click"></asp:button></td>
                    <td align=center><asp:button id="btnReset" Runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="btnReset_Click"></asp:button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colSpan="2"><asp:label id="lblStatus" Runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:label></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my code-behind for default.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Net.Mail;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    #region  "Send email"
    protected void btnSendmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer is obsolete in 2.0
        // System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient is the alternate class for this in 2.0
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

        try
        {
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text, txtName.Text);

            // You can specify the host name or ipaddress of your server
            // Default in IIS will be localhost 
            smtpClient.Host = "localhost";

            //Default port will be 25
            smtpClient.Port = 1159;

            //From address will be given as a MailAddress Object
            message.From = fromAddress;

            // To address collection of MailAddress
            message.To.Add("admin1@yoursite.com");
            message.Subject = "Feedback";

            // CC and BCC optional
            // MailAddressCollection class is used to send the email to various users
            // You can specify Address as new MailAddress("admin1@yoursite.com")
            message.CC.Add("admin1@yoursite.com");
            message.CC.Add("admin2@yoursite.com");

            // You can specify Address directly as string
            message.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("admin3@yoursite.com"));
            message.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("admin4@yoursite.com"));

            //Body can be Html or text format
            //Specify true if it  is html message
            message.IsBodyHtml = false;

            // Message body content
            message.Body = txtMessage.Text;

            // Send SMTP mail
            smtpClient.Send(message);

            lblStatus.Text = "Email successfully sent.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Send Email Failed.<br>" + ex.Message;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region "Reset"
    protected void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtName.Text = "";
        txtMessage.Text = "";
        txtEmail.Text = "";
    }
    #endregion
}
```

i m getting the error here

```
 // Send SMTP mail
 smtpClient.Send(message);
```

i dont know how to correct it.
my port no is 3168
i had tried to replace it.
but unable to resolve

the catch portion is getting "Failure sending Mail"
i m sending the detail/snapshort of error.

[image: error message]

[image]

[image: error message]

Comment: What is the ex.Message your getting?

Comment: Please only post the _relevant_ code and markup. You have posted so much that it is difficult to see the issue. Also post the actual error messages.

Comment: @Raja what exception you are getting at 'Send SMTP mail smtpClient.Send(message);'?

Comment: If you getting error please be gentle and write it.

Comment: @Reniuz  Error message is "Failure sending mail."

Comment: @Oded Error message is "Failure sending mail."

Comment: @Pleun Error message is "Failure sending mail."

Comment: @Raja post the ex.ToString();

Comment: There should be test in the exception after "Failure sending mail" - it will be something like System.Net.WebException and some text. This is the text people need to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Raja get the inner exception

Comment: @Neha i dont know About the inner expection.might be i am sending email through localhost-that would be problem.now i am trying to installed mail server.if possible will you tell me how to do it.

Comment: install mail server and then tell where you get stuck

Comment: @Neha still the problm is coming i have debug all the thing one by one.the expection error comes like this.so i have expanded and pasting the snapshort of error in the edit portion of question

Comment: @Neha i m not geeting the option to send the snapshort of error message.how to paste it here?

Comment: @Neha my inner sectior error is "Unable to connect to the remote serve"

Comment: Seems like a DNS problem.

From the command line of that server, can you successfully do "nslookup theHostNameFromYourPost"?

If this does not work either, double check the host name and consult with networking personnel.

Comment: @Neha i have Checked it again. It is Now showing problem in smtp server.My Smtp Server Setting is <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="rajiway2006@gmail.com">
        <network host="localhost" port="1159" userName="Raja Thakur" password="" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>

Comment: @Raja check your crendials is correct:<smtp from="rajiway2006@gmail.com"> <network host="localhost" port="1159" userName="Raja Thakur" password="" defaultCredentials="true" /> </smtp>

Comment: @Neha Dont you think I have written the same Stmp Server Setting

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat, I would say that your problem is the fact you have set localhost as your mail server. Do you even have a mail server installed locally? If you have access to a real mail server on your live site, try setting the mail server to that address with appropriate password and username info. Then see if them mail goes out.

Comment: i was thinking the same to resolve the error.can you please tell me how to installed mail server.